# Service won't stop when stopService method is called

Tags: android, service

I currently have a Service that runs fine when I start it but when I try to stop it using the stopService method its onDestroy method doesn't get called.

Here is the code I use to try to stop the Service

stop_Scan_Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopScanButton);

```
stop_Scan_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d("DEBUGSERVICE", "Stop Button pressed");
        Intent service = new Intent(CiceroEngine. CICERO_SERVICE);
        releaseBind();
        Log.d("Stop_Scan_Button", "Service: " + service.toString());
        stopService(service);
        Log.d("Stop_Scan_Button", "Service should stop! ");

        }   
});
```

Am I right in thinking that when stopService is used it calls the onDestroy method of the Service? When I press my stop scan button the `onDestroy()` method in my Service is not called.

Is there anything else I am missing that I should put in to  stop the service?

EDIT: to add `onServiceConnected()` gets called when stopService is run instead of `onServiceDisconnected()`, why would that be happening?

EDIT:**To add more info regards Binding**

I call bindService in the onCreate() method and I then have the releaseBind() method unbind the Service.

Here is the code for that method:

```
 public void releaseBind(){
    unbindService(this);
  }
```

So I presume that the unbinding is not my problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I am going to guess that your having a method call for `releaseBind()` means that you previously called `bindService()` on this service and that `releaseBind()` is calling `unbindService()`. If my guess is incorrect, please ignore this answer.

---

A service will shut down after all `bindService()` calls have had their corresponding `unbindService()` calls. If there are no bound clients, then the service will also need `stopService()` if and only if somebody called `startService()` on the service.

So, there are a few possibilities here:

1. You still have bound clients (e.g., other activities), in which case you cannot stop the service until they unbind
2. Since both `unbindService()` and `stopService()` are asynchronous, something might be going haywire with the timing, in which case you may get better luck if you call `stopService()` from your `ServiceConnection`'s `onServiceDisconnected()` method

Also, bear in mind that the exact timing of the service being destroyed is up to Android and may not be immediate. So, for example, if you are relying upon `onDestroy()` to cause your service to stop some work that is being done, consider using another trigger for that (e.g., activity calling a `stopDoingStuff()` method through the service binder interface).

Comment: I have edited my original question to include info about my binding, I do have it binding and then unbinding

Comment: Ummm, that code is totally messed up and is almost certainly contributing to your problem. `bindService()` and `unbindService()` are asynchronous and are guaranteed to fail the way you are using them. Unfortunately, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here, so I have no good way of advising you further.

Comment: Its just a two button UI, one to start the service and one to stop it.

I have taken the if statement out of my releaseBind() method leaving just unBindService(this); 

This appears to unregister the Service as when I click on it a second time I get the "Service not registered" error. 

However, stopService still doesn't appear to call the onDestroy() method in my Service, the background services still function

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have it working perfectly now, thanks for pointing out the flaw in my coding.

Comment: @CommonsWare What if we call stopSelf() when there are still activities bound to that service? Does that request get ignored?

Comment: @Pacerier: I have no idea. `stopSelf()` is not usually used with binding.

Comment: But `onServiceDisconnected()` is "called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed." I.e. it should not be called when there are no more binders.

Answer (score 11):

Are all your bindings closed?

> [A service can be used in two
>   ways.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife) The two modes are not
>   entirely
>   separate. You can bind to a service
>   that was started with startService().
>   For example, a background music
>   service could be started by calling
>   startService() with an Intent object
>   that identifies the music to play.
>   Only later, possibly when the user
>   wants to exercise some control over
>   the player or get information about
>   the current song, would an activity
>   establish a connection to the service
>   by calling bindService(). In cases
>   like this, stopService() will not
>   actually stop the service **until the
>   last binding is closed**

.

Comment: Yeh I only bind it once and then call releaseBind() to unbind

Answer (score 4):

hai guys sorry for the late answer but as far as i know i have successfull stop the service in this code: you may check a [link](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-stopstart-service-in-android.html) here.

```
public void onClick(View src) {
switch (src.getId()) {
case R.id.buttonStart:
  Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
  startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
  break;
case R.id.buttonStop:
  Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
  stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
  break;
}
}
```

and in services class:

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
       private static final String TAG = "MyService";


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

}
}
```