# How to stop a service?

Tags: android

I have a service [IntentService] which runs a 'timer task' scheduled to run after every 5 minutes. I start the service when my application is installed.

Now i want to stop my service [service runs a 'timer task'], but when i use stopService() method i am unable to stop my service. I tried to put a log in the onDestroy() method of my service but stopService() does not reaches there.

Also, since stopService() returns boolean i logged its output, it is returning false.

How should i stop it??

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop), it may help you.

Comment: ................................

Comment: @YaqubAhmad i dont bind my service anywhere.

Comment: @alchemist I want to achieve the same . Did you get this solved at your end?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a service [IntentService] which runs a 'timer task' scheduled to run after every 5 minutes.

Please do not do this. Users hate developers who do this and will force-stop your application using task killers or the Settings app. Please use `AlarmManager`, so you can take up less RAM and be more friendly to the user.

> I start the service when my application is installed.

This is not supported. In particular, as of Android 3.1, this is impossible, even by the undocumented hack you might be using.

> Now i want to stop my service [service runs a 'timer task'], but when i use stopService() method i am unable to stop my service.

Most likely, your service is already stopped. `IntentService` stops as soon as `onHandleIntent()` returns. `TimerTask` forks a thread to maintain its timer -- if you are creating this `TimerTask` in `onHandleIntent()`, you are leaking this thread. You have no way of ever stopping this thread. It will randomly go away once Android elects to terminate your process.

If, on the other hand, you get rid of the `TimerTask` and use `AlarmManager`, you can do your real periodic work in the `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()` method.