# Stop service doesn't work on android

Tags: android, service

I'm a student new to android, and I have an application which use background service.
I want to start/stop the service by clicking on a button, i'm doing it like this:

```
case R.id.enablepop:
        if (!(pop.runningFlag))
            startService(new Intent(mainScreen,PopUpService.class));
        return true;
case R.id.disablepop:
        if (pop.runningFlag)
                stopService(new Intent(mainScreen,PopUpService.class));
        return true;
```

In the onStart() function of the service I have runningFlag which I set to "true", then I create a thread that works while runningFlag is true.
I set the runningFlag to false on onDestroy().

The problem is that the service won't stop. Can someone help me plz?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop

Comment: How are you determining that "the service won't stop"?

Comment: I saw that, I didnt realy understant what I need to do, I dont overide onBind() function, maybe this is the problem?
Where do i need to put the onServiceDisconnect(), because I stop the service in Activity..

Comment: I know that the service is still running because i use Log.d() in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Handler, like here you can use Handler like Thread.

here is the example

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service{
    private Handler handler;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        handler.post(updateStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateStatus);
        handler = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateStatus);
        handler = null;
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private Runnable updateStatus = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do something here
            handler.postDelayed(updateStatus, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

here the handler can was initialized into the oncreate method now after that when onStart method invoked then the updateStatus object will invoked through the handler.post() which will start the run method of this Runnable object.

Now in this, this will invoked the run() at once and execute the statement at once only so for repeating this task call inside this method on specific delay time like here 1000 milliseconds so after complete all the execution it will again call after 1 sec and repeating this task this will continue until you cannot remove the runnable object from the handler, so basically that was call into the onDestroy()

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i tried it but it still doesnt work.
Do I need to stop the service like before with
stopService(new Intent(mainScreen,PopUpService.class));  ??

Comment: yes defenatly what happen Thread process and Service both are different so when you stop the service using stopService method but still Thread was running in background so to overcome this you can handle Thread using Runnable and Handler like this way

Comment: I used Log function to check whether the service is still working or not, and it continues to print something from the thread, so i guess it is still working.... Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: ok, if there is any case that I make startService(new Intent(mainScreen,PopUpService.class)) while the service is already running, can it make any problem?