# how can i stop service in activity

Tags: android

*I am writing this code on button click .

```
public void onstopServiceClickHandler(View view){       
        Intent intent=new Intent(DownloadQueueActivity.this, ProductDownloadService.class);
        stopService(intent);        
        //lv_productList.setAdapter(downloadQueueAdapter);
        //startServiceButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(_instance, "click stop service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }*
```

but service method onDestory is called.Service is not stop.Help me how to stop service in activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop

Comment: your button click is strange i never seen,follow me..

Answer (score 0):

**try this on button click ....**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent=new Intent(DownloadQueueActivity.this, ProductDownloadService.class);
        stopService(intent);
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call

```
 stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

service will stop when he can

Once requested to stop with stopSelf() or stopService(), the system destroys the service **as soon as possible.** It is from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping