# Android local service unbind issue

Tags: android, android-service

I created sample local service project as provided in Android Service article Extending the Binder class http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html.

Everything works fine. However the query is

With unbind(), service doesn't get stopped. Should i need to use stopSelf() explicitly if yes than what does unbind() does.

I have create sample project with three buttons -> start, stop and fetch

start --> to bind service

stop --> to unbind service

start --> to access method of service. (random number generation method)

Now access to:

1. start - binds the service
2. fetch - gets access to method of service
3. stop -  unbinds the service

Here i excepted that service will be unbind and destroyed. However

Step 4: fetch - this method still works and generates random number whereas expected was some sort of exception or may be force close.

(onServiceDisconnected will not be called: since it will be called only in case of crash)

Comment: [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/android-service-wont-stop) seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: "With unbind(), service doesn't get stopped." -- how have you determined this? And what do you mean by "stopped"?

Comment: @CommonsWare: i have edited my question for clarity.

Comment: @FishBreath: Thanks for adding the links that has help me. How about my query. Why i am able to execute Step 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a remote service -- where the service you bind to is in another process -- attempting to call a method on the binder proxy after unbinding should result in a `RemoteException`.

For a local service -- where the service is still in your process -- attempting to call a method on the binder after unbinding may still work. The binder in this case is the very same object that your service returned via `onBind()`. Garbage collection rules state that if you hold onto the binder, the binder cannot be garbage collected.

However, calling methods on a binder after unbinding is dangerous and poor form. The *service* thinks it was destroyed. If there is anything your binder depends upon that the service cleaned up in `onDestroy()`, *that* might cause a crash. Similarly, you are leaking the service's memory, until you allow the binder to be garbage collected.

BTW, I hope your service is doing something more meaningful than "generates random number". You do not need a service for that.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. Regarding random number generation :) as already mentioned in my query; it is a sample project to study service.