# How to cancel an alarm in service from an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a brodcastReciver , an activity and a service , in the activity i send an intent to service to set an alarm , and alarm is sending broadcast to brodcastReciver to show toast.
but i cant cancel alarm from activiy. here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button start, stop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            start();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stop();
        }
    });

}

void stop() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Reci.class);
    i.putExtra("c", "cancel");
    startService(i);
    Toast.makeText(this, "stop clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

void start() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Serv.class);
    i.putExtra("d", "do");
    startService(i);
    Toast.makeText(this, "start clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

 }
```

service :

```
public class Serv extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.getStringExtra("d").equalsIgnoreCase("do")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Reci.class)
                .setAction("ir.test.code.Reci.noti");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234, i, 0);
        G.AM.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, 5000, pi);

    } else if (intent.getStringExtra("c").equalsIgnoreCase("cancel")) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Reci.class)
                .setAction("ir.test.code.Reci.noti");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234, i, 0);
        G.AM.cancel(pi);
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

broadcastReciver

```
public class Reci extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("ir.test.code.Reci.noti")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "ir.test.code.Reci.noti",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}
```

and Application class :

```
public class G extends Application{

public static AlarmManager AM;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AM = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

}
```

what should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176375/service-wont-stop-when-stopservice-method-is-called

Comment: alarm_manager.cancel(your_pendingintent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not starting service because of diffent class name you provided ...change void stop()  method

Intent i = new Intent(this, Reci.class);

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Serv.class);
```

in **stop() method of mainactivity**

Comment: thank you , there was also another problem in my if else statement in service , finally i solved my problem with your quide.